# drupal 6 jquery module additions

Tags: 7, users, javascript

this is what the module has in it now for basic toggle of the login box.

```
   Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan = function() {
  $("#toboggan-login-link").click(
    function () {
      $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("fast");
      this.blur();
      return false;
    }
  );
};
```

I hacked the module's js file to this to get the function i needed but i dont want to have to do that if there is a better way.

```
Drupal.logintoboggan_toggleboggan = function() {
  $("#toboggan-login-link").click(
    function () {
      $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("slow", function() {
         if($(this).css('display') == 'block'){
                 $("#art-main").append('<div class="outer-login"></div>');
                     $(".outer-login").click( function () {
                          $("#toboggan-login").slideToggle("fast");
                          $(this).remove();
                     });
      } else{
          $(".outer-login").remove();
      }
      });


      this.blur();
      return false;
    }
  );
```

I have tried unset for the logintoboggan module but that didnt seem to work.

Comment: i tried to unset the jquery file for the module in the template file and in a custom module but neither one worked. Drupal forum makes mention of jquery update causing issue with unset so i need another alternative.

Comment: i decided to leave the additions within the module and everything works fine.